# Carregar dinamicamente do banco e montar um treeview no cshtml não estou conseguindo

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

é o seguinte. Não estou conseguindo os resultados satisfatórios na montagem de uma arvore usando checkbox como em um treeview. Bem, quando coloco os dados fixos funciona muito bem. Mas quando trago os dados do BD, aí que complica, ou seja, não funciona. A lógica é a seguinte para entenderem. Tenho alguns dados chaves, vindos do bando, que são: MOTIVO, UNIDADE_NEGÓCIO, FAMILIA e claro o produto(tudo medicamentos). Existe uma LINQ que me traz essas informações para eu montar a árvore. Essa LINQ, por enquanto me traz tudo e serializo e envio para uma função JQUERY. Nessa função, eu faço um EACH no resultado da que vem da controller(LINQ), monto os nós e decarrego o HTML então na página. Na função, faço uns IF's para que não se repita os nomes nos nós. Não dá para fazer um distinct, pois tenho várias vezes o mesmo MOTIVO mas para ID diferentes e assim para os demais, por isso os IF's na jquery. O que está acontecendo? Não monta os checkbox's, traz as informações, mas não monta os checkbox e por isso não cria a barra de scroll lateralmente. Não vou escrever muito senão fica inelegível, mas veja os códigos abaixo:

1) Esse código com dados fakes funciona e é assim que gostaria. Os includes de javascript e CSS estão ok, senão não funcionava.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxCodTipo">UF:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxCodTipo" id="cbxCodTipo" onchange=" return MontaCidades();">
                <option value="00">Selecione um estado</option>
                <option value="AC">ACRE</option>
                <option value="AL">ALAGOAS</option>
                <option value="AP">AMAPÁ</option>
                <option value="AM">AMAZONAS</option>
                <option value="BA">BAHIA</option>
                <option value="CE">CEARÁ</option>
                <option value="DF">DISTRITO FEDERAL</option>
                <option value="ES">ESPÍRITO SANTO</option>
                <option value="GO">GOIÁS</option>
                <option value="MA">MARANHÃO</option>
                <option value="MT">MATO GROSSO</option>
                <option value="MS">MATO GROSSO DO SUL</option>
                <option value="MG">MINAS GERAIS</option>
                <option value="PA">PARÁ</option>
                <option value="PB">PARAÍBA</option>
                <option value="PR">PARANÁ</option>
                <option value="PE">PERNAMBUCO</option>
                <option value="PI">PIAUÍ</option>
                <option value="RJ">RIO DE JANEIRO</option>
                <option value="RN">RIO GRANDE DO NORTE</option>
                <option value="RS">RIO GRANDE DO SUL</option>
                <option value="RO">RONDÔNIA</option>
                <option value="RR">RORAIMA</option>
                <option value="SC">SANTA CATARINA</option>
                <option value="SP">SÃO PAULO</option>
                <option value="SE">SERGIPE</option>
                <option value="TO">TOCANTINS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="cbxCidade">Cidade:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="cbxCidade" id="cbxCidade"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxRede">Rede:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxRede" id="cbxRede"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="cbxRede">Descrição:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="cbxDescricao" id="cbxDescricao"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxProduto">Produto:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxProduto" id="cbxProduto"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxUnNegocio">Unidade Negócio:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxUnNegocio" id="cbxUnNegocio"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div id="content">
    <div class="listTree"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" return MontaArvore();">Pesquisar</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id='jqxWidget'>
<div style='float: left; width:auto;'>
    <div id='jqxTree' style='visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 20px;'>
        <ul>
            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                Produto
                <ul>
                    <li item-expanded='true'>
                        MIP
                        <ul>
                            <li item-expanded='true'>
                                Família: ACCUVIT
                                <ul>
                                    <li>ACCUVIT COMREV FRX30</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li item-expanded='true'>
                                Família: FLOGORAL
                                <ul>
                                    <li>FLOGORAL SPRAY CEREJA CTX30ML</li>
                                    <li>FLOGORAL SPRAY MENTA CTX30ML</li>
                                    <li>FLOGORAL CREM DENTAL CTX70G</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div style='margin-left: 60px; float: left;'>
        <div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
            <input id='jqxCheckBox' type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtObs">Observação:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea id="txtObs" style="width: 450px;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="content">
        <div class="listTree"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ">Gravar</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index", "Home", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
    </div>
```

Aqui está o meu controller com a LINQ.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ArvoreAcao(string _uf)
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
                                  from apr in db.Apresentacao.Where(apr => apr.Codigo_Apresentacao == rup.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                  from pdv in db.PDV.Where(pdv => pdv.CodigoPDV == rup.CodigoPDV)
                                  from mot in db.Motivo.Where(mot => mot.IDMotivo == rup.IDMotivo)

                                  select new {
                                      rup.IDRuptura,
                                      rup.DataRuptura,
                                      rup.IDMotivo,
                                      mot.Motivo1,
                                      rup.IDOrigem,
                                      rup.CodigoPDV,
                                      pdv.UF,
                                      pdv.Cidade,
                                      loja = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao,
                                      rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                                      apr.Unidade_Negocio,
                                      apr.Franquia,
                                      apr.Familia,
                                      apr.Descricao}).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(apr => apr.Descricao);

            return Json(new { monta_arvore }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

E por último meu JQUERY, onde está o problema.

```
function MontaArvore() {

    var str = "";
    var motivo = "";
    var unidade_neg = "";
    var familia = "";

    $.ajax({

        url: '/Acao/ArvoreAcao',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        success: function (data) {

            $(data.monta_arvore).each(function () {

                if (motivo != this.Motivo1) {
                    str += '<ul>';
                    str += '<li item-checked="false" item-expanded="false">';
                    str += this.Motivo1;
                }

                if (unidade_neg != this.Unidade_Negocio) {
                    str += '<ul>';
                    str += '<li item-expanded="false">';
                    str += this.Unidade_Negocio;
                }

                if (familia != this.Familia) {
                str += '<ul>';
                str += '<li item-expanded="false">';
                    str += this.Familia;
                }
                str += '<ul>';
                    str += '<li>' + this.Descricao + '</li>';
                str += '</ul>';

                str += '</li>';//Familia
                str += '</ul>';//Familia

                str += '</li>';//Unidade de negocio
                str += '</ul>';//Unidade de negocio

                motivo = this.Motivo1;
                unidade_neg = this.Unidade_Negocio;
                familia = this.Familia;
            });

            str += '</li>';//li item-checked após o ul principal
            str += '</ul>';

            $('#jqxTree').html(str);
            str = "";
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    })
}
```

Pode ser algum `<UL>` ou alguma `<LI>`, sei lá, qualquer coisa assim. A questão é que os checks não são montados e com os dados fakes eles(checks) ficam ótimos. Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda. Obrigado.

Comment: Fui fazendo nível a nível primeiro, tipo, comecei somente com apenas um nível. Não monta os checkboxes. Aparece as informações, porem sem os checks, apenas com aquele pontinho que são criados pelas tag's <li>.

Comment: Será que o HTML resultante ficou bem formatado?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente sua lógica para fechar as tags html não estão corretas.

Coloquei comentários no código abaixo mostrando que você precisa colocar pontos de controle pra abrir e fechar as tags html senão não será renderizado da maneira que deseja.

```
function MontaArvore() {

var str = "";
var motivo = "";
var unidade_neg = "";
var familia = "";

$.ajax({

    url: '/Acao/ArvoreAcao',
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.monta_arvore).each(function () {

            if (motivo != this.Motivo1) {
                str += '<ul>';
                str += '<li item-checked="false" item-expanded="false">';
                str += this.Motivo1;
            }

            if (unidade_neg != this.Unidade_Negocio) {
                str += '<ul>';
                str += '<li item-expanded="false">';
                str += this.Unidade_Negocio;
            }

            if (familia != this.Familia) {
            str += '<ul>';
            str += '<li item-expanded="false">';
                str += this.Familia;
            }
            str += '<ul>';
                str += '<li>' + this.Descricao + '</li>';
            str += '</ul>';

            // A TAG ESTÁ SENDO FECHADA SEM SABER SE FOI ABERTA
            // É PRECISO SABER SE ENTROU DENTRO DO IF PRA PODER FECHA-LA
            str += '</li>';//Familia
            str += '</ul>';//Familia

            // A TAG ESTÁ SENDO FECHADA SEM SABER SE FOI ABERTA
            // É PRECISO SABER SE ENTROU DENTRO DO IF PRA PODER FECHA-LA
            str += '</li>';//Unidade de negocio
            str += '</ul>';//Unidade de negocio

            motivo = this.Motivo1;
            unidade_neg = this.Unidade_Negocio;
            familia = this.Familia;
        });

        // NESSE PONTO VC TA FECHANDO UMA TAG Q NÃO SABE SE FOI CRIADA
        // ESSA TAG TEM Q TER ENTRADO NO IF MOTIVO PRA TER SIDO ABERTA
        str += '</li>';//li item-checked após o ul principal
        str += '</ul>';

        $('#jqxTree').html(str);
        str = "";
    },
    error: function (error) {

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem um (if) abrir uma tag  teria que tambem ter um (if) para controlar o fechamento dela, só isso.

Comment: As tag's estão sendo fechadas fora dos if's, mas estão. Isso não está correto? Fiz sem o if, direto e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Luidy, bom dia. Da forma que você colocou, eu já havia feito e sem resultado. A consulta está ok e os dados estão vindo sim na página. Só que sem os checkboxes e sem a barra de scroll. Eu tenho nessa consulta, sem filtro, um total de 11 mil registros, mas já fiz com um também e nada. Já alterei de diversas formas e nenhum deles eu consegui montar os check's. Se eu fixar os dados na view aí funciona, com o mesmo código que está aí, só não via jquery.

Comment: user2903558, fiz isso e mesmo assim não funciona. Só quero dizer aos colegas, que somente os check's não funcionam. O restante está ok.

Answer (score 0):

Quando vc usa o método

```
$('#jqxTree').html(str);
```

vc sobrescreve tudo que está dentro da div id="jqxTree", e o checkbox (jqxCheckBox) vc não mexe em momento nenhum.

Outra coisa é que se vc quer montar uma lista de checkboxes vc deveria ir colocando inputs dentro das li's, porém vc está apenas montando as li's sem colocar nada nele, exemplo:

```
if (motivo != this.Motivo1) {
            str += '<ul>';
            str += '<li><input type="checkbox" name="motivo1" value="seu valor" checked="true or false">';
            str += this.Motivo1;
}
```

Experimente criar os checkboxes dentro das li's e passar o valor que vc quer para esses ceckboxes, deve funcionar.

Comment: Não, esses inputs não posso colocar. O jqxtree já tem um js que faz tudo isso. Ele não precisa dos inputs, pois funciona perfeitamente. É um componente esse cara. Somente em run time com jquery é que tá dando pau. Estou fazendo de outra forma, mas vou tentar assim, mas sem os inputs, pois eles irão matar meus checkbox's.