# Pegar Model na View com os valores vindos do banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

Tenho essa classe:

```
public class MontaArvoreAcao
{
    public int IDRuptura { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataRuptura { get; set; }
    public int IDMotivo { get; set; }
    public string Motivo { get; set; }
    public int IDOrigem { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPDV { get; set; }
    public string UF { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Codigo_Apresentacao { get; set; }
    public string Unidade_Negocio { get; set; }
    public string Franquia { get; set; }
    public string Familia { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

A finalidade dessa classe é para eu ter uma Model que eu possa pegar na minha view e trabalhar com ela lá. Essa classe(Model) será alimentada com esse código na controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ArvoreAcao(string _uf)
{
    RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();    
    var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
       from apr in db.Apresentacao.Where(apr => apr.Codigo_Apresentacao == rup.Codigo_Apresentacao)
       from pdv in db.PDV.Where(pdv => pdv.CodigoPDV == rup.CodigoPDV)
       from mot in db.Motivo.Where(mot => mot.IDMotivo == rup.IDMotivo)
           select new {
               rup.IDRuptura,
               rup.DataRuptura,
               rup.IDMotivo,
               mot.Motivo1,
               rup.IDOrigem,
               rup.CodigoPDV,
               pdv.UF,
               pdv.Cidade,
               loja = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao,
               rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
               apr.Unidade_Negocio,
               apr.Franquia,
               apr.Familia,
               apr.Descricao}).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(apr => apr.Descricao);

    ViewBag.result_arvore = monta_arvore;    
    return Json(new { monta_arvore}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

A dúvida é: Como eu faço para pegar essa Model na View com todos os valores vindo da linq acima, ou seja, do banco de dados? Uma pergunta a mais: Todos os ID's dessa classe são Foreign Key. Está correto a forma de representar uma Foreign Key como está na classe ou tenho que fazer um ICollection?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer utilizar a sua classe MontaArvoreAcao sendo a Model da sua View.

A ação ArvoreAcao da sua controller está retornando um JsonResult. Quando se usa um retorno Json para uma View você está serializando um objeto e retornando um JsonData. Se você continuar fazendo da maneira com que está propondo acima terá que tratar via javascript/JQuery o retorno para a sua View e então você teria algo como:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "SuaController/ArvoreAcao",
  data: { _uf : seuCampoUf },
  success: function (montaArvore) {
         // Aqui utiliza sua entidade e coloca os valores nos 
         // campos/tags html que deseja utilizando por exemplo montaArvore.Descricao
});
```

Se seu objetivo é utilizar a entidade MontarArvoreAcao como Model de uma View, você pode mudar algumas coisas na sua Controller como:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ArvoreAcao(string _uf)
{
    // Faz o que é necessário

    return View(monta_arvore);
}
```

E na sua View você teria que declarar algo como:

```
@model MontaArvoreAcao
```

Nesse caso você conseguiria utilizar a Model dentro da View.

Há um outro detalhe que você está colocando a entidade monta_arvore para dentro de uma ViewBag. Nesse caso você conseguiria também utilizar a sua ViewBag dentro da View.

Comment: Luidy, inicialmente estava assim e copiei e mandei como estava. Dessa forma não tenho problemas com nada, exceto que na View eu preciso montar uns checkbox e com Jquery não está montando. Traz as informações, mas não monta os check's conforme coloquei em outro post. Aí então, tive a idéia de fazer diretamente no cshtml para ver se consigo funcionar.

Comment: Olá, você conseguiu ajuda no seu outro post de como montar os checkboxes ? Se não, mande o link para que eu possa ver e tentar ajudá-lo, por favor. Abs.

Comment: Não, ainda está aberto. Se eu conseguir fazer com jquery é tudo que eu gostaria.

Comment: Qual o link do seu post?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/carregar-dinamicamente-do-banco-e-montar-um-treeview-no-cshtml-n%C3%A3o-estou-consegu